# How to preprocess and predict for single image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

How can I preprocess and predict on a single image?
Here is the neural network and what I have tried.

I have resized all of the training images to `50x50` and applied gray-scale.

```py
def prepare(filepath):
        IMAGE_SIZE = 50
        test_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(filepath, target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        test_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(test_image)
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
        test_image = test_image.reshape(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

        return test_image

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()    
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))    # Simple Dense Layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))    # Simple Dense Layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax))   # Output layer

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
test_image = prepare('dog.jpg')
result = model.predict(test_image)
```

This is the error I am getting:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer:
>   expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3600 but received input
>   with shape [None, 150]

Comment: It looks like the model is expecting images of size 60x60 (3600 pixels in total). You are also reshaping the image to have 3 channels, but it's a grey-scale so that might also be an issue.